# How to create personalized urls in php?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to convert an URL like this:

`http://somesocial.com/SomeSocial/success/profile?search_user=exampleuser01`

Into a personalized URL like this: http://somesocial.com/exampleuser01

I've tried creating a folder with a file inside `success/preview/user_preview.php`
 which is a copy of profile.php to get the parameter from  'search_user' with `$profile_id = $_GET['profile_id']` and `header('Location:'.'success/profile?'.$profile_id);` To redirect the searched user for his original link.

Modified my .htaccess to:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^success/preview/user_preview?search_user=
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ success/preview/user_preview?search_user=$1 [L]
```

This works perfectly, but every time I try to access a file from the main dir (i.e Index.php) it redirects me to `http://somesocial.com/SomeSocial/success/profile.php?search_user=Index.php`

Why?

Comment: Here's how you should think about this: anything that's not one of the directories/files in the system and contains a GET parameter should be treated and rewritten to: `/SomeSocial/success/profile?search_user=requestName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reordering your rule wit more restrictive conditions:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ success/preview/user_preview?search_user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: http://somesocial.com/index.php / http://somesocial.com/exampleuser01 it returns the same page lol

Comment: You need to provide full details of the symotoms you are seeing since I cant guess it. Are you getting 404 for `http://somesocial.com/exampleuser01`? Is .htaccess enabled? Are there any other .htaccess files out there etc

Comment: I'm getting user_preview.php without css applied just html but this php file should redirect me to his orignal link. And ofc .htccess is enabled.

Comment: That means code is working fine. For css/js your problem is relative links, just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: That's why twitter (twitpic) / facebook (a.kamaid) uses another domain for the photos? I think i undestood.